How can i correctly configure the websocket
in springboot i did this Websocket config  and i have
i am using as restapi( it should send notification to specific user 
and this is the react native side where i should (as a receiver ) to see list of notifications that were sent to me but it's not working  
i was expecting to see list of notification that are sent to me (as a receiver)

This question is similar to: How to implement real time notification with springboot and react js. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
